# How to find the dimensions of variables having a fixed sequential format in R?

Tags: r

I have a number of data frames stored in my environment having different dimensions. However, these data frames have similar names like `a1`, `a2`, `a3` and so on until `a10`.

Now instead of doing `dim(a1)`, `dim(a2)` for each data frame I want to prepare a loop which can give me the dimension of all these data frames at once. I have used the following code:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  dim(get(paste0("a", i)))
}
```

However this is not giving any result. Please help

Comment: You don't do anything with the return value of `dim`, that's why you don't see any output. `print(dim(get(paste0("a", i))))` would show you the dimensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to store the output of a loop in a list:

```
lapply(paste0("a", c(1,10)), function(x)dim(get(x)))
```

Comment: There's also `mget`, i.e. `lapply(mget(paste0("a", 1:10)), dim)`

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: @docendodiscimus Could you please explain the difference between get and mget?

Comment: @RahulSinghSyunari, just read the documentation: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/get.html

Comment: ohh..my bad..thnx:)

Answer (score 2):

@user1981275 's answer has reminded me I always forget the `get()`

`for()` loops in R are not often a good idea.

First, get the data frames into a list:

```
dfs <- ls(pattern = "a")
```

Then `lapply()` over that list:

```
lapply(dfs, function(x) {dim(get(x))})
```

If you have other objects loaded in your environment with an "a" in your `pattern =` match will need to be more sophisticated

Comment: Thanks for your help Phil.However I would still need to use "get" here..  lapply(dfs,function(x) dim(get(x))